# Videos written with moviepy on amazon aws S3 are empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, moviepy

I am working on processing a dataset of large videos (~100 GB) for a collaborative project. To make it easier to share data and results, I am keeping all videos remotely on an amazon S3 bucket, and processing it by mounting the bucket on an EC2 instance.

One of the processing steps I am trying to do involves cropping the videos, and rewriting them into smaller segments. I am doing this with moviepy, splitting the video with the subclip method and calling:

```
subclip.write_videofile("PathtoS3Bucket"+VideoName.split('.')[0]+'part' +str(segment)+ '.mp4',codec = 'mpeg4',bitrate = "1500k",threads = 2)
```

I found that when the videos are too large (parameters set as above) calls to this function will sometimes generate empty files in my S3 bucket (~10% of the time). Does anyone have insight into features of moviepy/ffmpeg/S3 that would lead to this?

Comment: How are you "mounting" S3 to your system? It is recommended not to use tools such as `s3fs` because these merely simulate a file system, whereas Amazon S3 is an object storage system. It is generally better to create files locally, then copy them to S3 using standard API calls.

Comment: I was using s3fs to create a link to S3. I found that I would get OOM errors when trying to store the files locally, and writing to S3 seemed more efficient than trying to create new instances. I'm using a p2xlarge instance currently to do this processing, but is there another that I should consider? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "OOM errors when trying to store the files locally"? Are you saying you ran out of RAM, or ran out of disk storage space? I would suggest focussing on getting that to work correctly using the local disk, then after that look at how to incorporate S3.

Comment: Yes, apologies- I ran out of disk storage space. I will do so, thank you for your advice!

Comment: You can increase the size of the Amazon EBS disk volume attached to the instance. You might also want to experiment with different Instance Types. The P2 family has attached GPUs, which is comparatively expensive so make sure your encoding process is making use of the GPUs.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply here- I resolved the issue by first writing videos to ethereal storage in the local disk of a C5d instance, and then uploading to S3 from there. Thank you for all the help! If you would like to compile your comments into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended not to use tools such as `s3fs` because these merely simulate a file system, whereas Amazon S3 is an object storage system.

It is generally better to create files locally, then copy them to S3 using standard API calls.